# Excel VBA running all If statements even though all conditions aren't being met

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-tables, listobject

My sheet has a table with many columns, but only the first two columns are input fields and the remaining have formulas based on the values in the first two columns. Instead of manually entering the information into the first few columns, I've set up two input fields outside of the table that I would like, once a button with an assigned macro has been clicked, to have transferred into the table.

The VBA code I wrote has several If-Then statements. The first statement returns a msgbox if the first input field (B3) is blank. The second statement returns a msgbox if the second input field (B4) is blank. The third If-Then statement will transfer the info from B3 and B4 into the next available table row if B3 and B4 are not blank.

If I enter information into B3 and B4, the code works fine. The problem comes when B3 and B4 are blank - I receive the appropriate msgbox, but the blank information still gets added as a new row to the table. If I click my button when there is no info in B3 and B4, it will keep giving me the msgbox while also adding rows to my table. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub AddToPortfolio()

Dim portfolio As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow

Set portfolio = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set table_list_object = portfolio.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

  If portfolio.Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter CUSIP ID"
     portfolio.Range("B3").Select
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If portfolio.Range("B4").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Quantity"
     portfolio.Range("B4").Select
  End If

  If portfolio.Range("B3").Value <> "" And portfolio.Range("B4").Value <> "" Then
     table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = portfolio.Range("B3").Value
     table_object_row.Range(1, 2).Value = portfolio.Range("B4").Value
  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Set table_list_object = portfolio.ListObjects(1) Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add --> can you please try to move these two lines inside the last IF statement? Additionally, put an "Exit Sub" inside your second if statement as well.

Comment: Govind, you are a life saver! I made the adjustments you mentioned and it worked! I also modified the script a little bit and it seems to be giving me another issue. Once B3 and B4 have information in them, they are getting added to the last row of the table (which is good). Unfortunately, there is another row being added immediately after that one too. How can I get it to just add B3 and B4 to the last row and then stop there? Here is the code:

Comment: I can't post my code again - I'm going to create a new post and link it here. Sorry about that, one second.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Set table_list_object = portfolio.ListObjects(1)
  Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
```

can you please try to move these two lines inside the last IF statement? Additionally, put an "Exit Sub" inside your second if statement as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Govind! It works, but I've run into another minor issue. After adding the last row of information (only when B3 and B4 have text in them), the code adds another row to my table. Instead of the information from B3 and B4 being the last row in my table, they are the second to last row (the last row now being just an empty row). Do you know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

### Write to New Row in Table

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddToPortfolio()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim Cell1 As Range: Set Cell1 = ws.Range("B3")
    Dim Cell2 As Range: Set Cell2 = ws.Range("B4")

    If checkEmpty(Cell1, "Please Enter CUSIP ID") Then Exit Sub
    If checkEmpty(Cell2, "Please Enter Quantity") Then Exit Sub

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Dim tblRow As ListRow: Set tblRow = tbl.ListRows.Add
    tblRow.Range(1, 1).Value = Cell1.Value
    tblRow.Range(1, 2).Value = Cell2.Value
    ' To avoid duplicates:
    Union(Cell1, Cell2).ClearContents

End Sub

Function checkEmpty(SourceCell As Range, ByVal Message As String) As Boolean
    If SourceCell.Value = Empty Then
        checkEmpty = True
        SourceCell.Select
        MsgBox Message
    End If
End Function
```